# What is the best way to select a node in a remote DOM?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, dom, web-worker

I need a little bit of advice on a quite unusual subject.

As a part of a project I'm involved in, I need to develop a JS library, which would make DOM APIs available in a Web Worker. The idea is to be able to effortlessly run (almost) any client-side JS in a Worker, and one of the many issues I faced is the correct node identification between threads. In other words, when I make changes to some `<div>` from Web Worker, I need to be sure that they will be applied exactly to the `<div>` I'm targeting in the actual DOM.

Here's where I got so far. Every DOM Node has its copy in the Web Worker and internal unique ID. Whenever a node gets modified, the lib calculates a position-based selector and then passes it to the main thread alongside with a patch. Basically:

```
1. onMutation -> getSelector(node)                      // Worker
2. postMessage([mutation, selector])                    // Worker --> Main
3. selectNode(selector) -> applyMutation(node, mutaion) // Main
```

Here's a simplified version of the function that calculates the selector, just to give you a general idea of what it is:

```
function getSelector(node, root) {
  let selector = [];
  while (node !== root) {
    selector.unshift(node.parentNode.childNodes.indexOf(node));
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return selector;
}
```

That would've been a perfect solution if browsers didn't occasionally mess up the tree structure by doing nasty things like inserting empty text nodes or moving invisible nodes around. And if that happens, the Web Worker DOM becomes invalid and starts producing incorrect selectors. So I wonder if there's a more reliable way to identify the node without marking it with attributes or anything like that. Is there a simpler solution that I'm missing out? (that'd be embarrassing, but good to know anyway)

Looking forward to your thoughts on this and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why though? You can only manipulate the DOM on the main thread. This seems very redundant. You don't gain any performance from this. Actually you create over-head.

Comment: @Darkrum yeah in some cases it's less performant, but the main reason we're doing it is because we need to run untrusted code (don't ask why), and putting it in a Web Worker seems to be the best way to safely sandbox it.

Comment: Web workers aren't for sand boxing untrusted code. Malicious code in a web worker can cause alot of havoc. But if you're hell bent on this. Which i strongly condemn​ you could hold the reference to the element in the closure created and when the web worker messages back you still have the reference in the calling function.

Comment: @Darkrum Sure, Web Workers are meant to be used for other purposes, but we didn't really have a choice. Being a lazy developer, I did quite a research before actually starting to work on it, and nothing else (iframes, Google Caja etc) seemed to meet our requirements. Anyway, thanks for suggestion!